# How to navigate from identity page to page in different folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Web Application (using Razor pages not controllers) and I am trying to amend the register (identity) page so that once the user has registered (by an admin whos logged in already) it navigates to a Manage roles page and passes the UserId of the user just created.

This is my folder structure:

[image: FOLDER STRUCTURE]

Currently I'm on the register page which is within the following path:

Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml

and I am trying to navigate to a page thats simply within the Pages folder: Pages/ManageRoles.cshtml

Here is my code:

```
return RedirectToPage("./ManageRoles", new { id = user.Id });
```

but it doesn't work and gives me an error saying No page named './ManageRoles' matches the supplied values. I have also tried the code without the ./ and it still gave me the same error. I have also tried it without the userId part and it still didnt work.

Could someone help me?

Comment: All of your pages should have the same root folder

Comment: I used the default identity setup that came with the program, it wasn't me who added it. When i created my application, it was already there and the index which my whole application is based on was already in the Pages folder.

Comment: If you can navigate to a page under "Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml", you've probably changed the root directory (probably in your startup class). You'll need to move the content under the default pages folder to that configured directory.

Comment: Did you try ` RedirectToPage("/ManageRoles", new { id = user.Id });` without the leading period?

Comment: @BronDavies That worked perfectly, thank you! I feel stupid now lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it to this and it worked:

```
return RedirectToPage("/ManageRoles", new { UserId = user.Id });
```